# UISearchDisplayController resets contentInset

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i try to set a custom contentInset to a UISearchdisplayControllers searchResultsTableView.

after initializing it

```
_searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_searchController.delegate = self;
_searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
_searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
```

i set the contentInset

```
_searchController.searchResultsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
```

logging this inset correctly displays the offset of 2 at the bottom.
after the searchbar becomes active the Controller resettes the value fist to about -210px and after scrolling a little bit in the table view it sets the value back to 0px.

any ideas why this is happening? the Controller and the TableView work fine, but i am not able to set a custom contentInset.

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

in _searchController.delegate,  add followed code

```
    - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        controller.searchResultsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    }
```